# Interchanging differentiation and evaluation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

Suppose $f(x,y)\in \mathcal{C}^2$ (twice continuously differentiable, also real). When can you say
$$f_x(x,y)\Biggr|_{y=0} = \partial_x\left(f(x,0)\right)$$
with the loosest possible restrictions? (I'd prefer to not have to bound the derivative, which I know works.)

Edit: (based on comment below) In particular, is it true for all $f(x,y)\in \mathcal{C}^2$ (i.e. no additional assumptions)?

Comment: Isn't this true whenever $f\in C^2$?

Comment: @WilliamStagner that's basically my question. =) Can you reference me somewhere?

Comment: There is a solution here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684238/interchanging-partial-differentiation-with-evaluation-along-a-curve?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Define the following

$$f(x,y) = \cases{ (x^2+y^2) \sin (\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) & (x,y) $\neq$ (0,0)\\
                    0 & (x,y) = (0,0)}$$

Then $f$ does not have continuous partial derivatives at the origin; however, it is easily verified that $\partial_x f(x,0)$ is, in fact, differentiable at the origin.

I think continuity of the partial derivatives is required in order for the operations to commute.

Comment: Cool example. My $f(x,y)$ is twice continuously differentiable though, so maybe I'm still okay.